# Why are my hidden input not being passed in the model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Dto class with nested classes im using to bind a model to my view.
The nested class has an `id` property that needs to be passed back into my app service, but so far im getting `null`

Some things i've tried are

```
<input asp-for="StoreWalk.Department.Id" type="hidden" />
@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.StoreWalk.Department.Id)
<input type="hidden" name="version" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Version" />
<input type="hidden" name="department.id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="department_id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
<input type="hidden" id="StoreWalk_Department_Id" name="department_id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
```

My model class

```
public class CreateOrEditStoreWalkViewModel
{
    public CreateOrEditStoreWalkDto StoreWalk { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditMode => StoreWalk.Id.HasValue;
}


public class CreateOrEditStoreWalkDto : EntityDto<int?>
{
    // Id property is implemented in `EntityDto` as int?

    [Required]
    public string Store { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public DepartmentsDto Department { get; set; }
}


public class DepartmentsDto : EntityDto
{
    // Id property is implemented in `EntityDto`
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`EntityDto` can be found here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Application/Services/Dto/EntityDto.cs

My View.cshtml

```
    <form name="StoreWalkInformationsForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">

        @if (Model.IsEditMode)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Id" />
        }


        // Note, im not trying all at once, these are just what ive tried so far

        <input asp-for="StoreWalk.Department.Id" type="hidden" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.StoreWalk.Department.Id)
        <input type="hidden" name="version" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Version" />
        <input type="hidden" name="department.id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="department_id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" id="StoreWalk_Department_Id" name="department_id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />

        .........
  </form>
```

I expect the `department.id` to be set but `department` is always null.
[image]

Comment: Is the hidden field within the form tag you are submitting back?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan it is, i've updated my question with my view's code

Comment: @lizzy91 Please edit your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. You are missing several classes like the controllers and `EntityDto` class. Also get and output the request form parameter names you receive in your controller to see what the browser is sending.

Comment: Show the actual `Id` property definition, i.e. `EntityDto`. Also, since I'm assuming it's a nullable int, since you're getting null and not 0, show where you are setting it to some actual value, i.e. your mapping code or however that's happening. Can you confirm that it has a value in the actual HTML source (i.e. view source).

Comment: Remove your custom `name` attributes. ASP.NET generates its own `name` attribute values for model-binding.

Comment: I added `EntityDto` to my question. `Id` is `int?` and is expected to be null, I'm trying to pass `Department.Id` which is `int`. In html, i see the correct value set to the hidden input, but i think its not being picked up because of the `id` or `name` property fails to bind to the model.

Comment: There should be no issue with something like `<input asp-for="StoreWalk.Department.Id" type="hidden" />`. Most of the rest of the things you tried are broken, though, and definitely wouldn't work at all. In other words, the name attribute should actually end up as something like `name="StoreWalk.Department.Id"`... `name="department_id"`, is just not right at all.

Comment: `<input asp-for="StoreWalk.Department.Id" type="hidden" />` generated the following output, which also looks correct to me (thanks for confirming), but my `Department` class is still null. Output: `<input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="StoreWalk_Department_Id" name="StoreWalk.Department.Id" value="8">`

Comment: As long as 1 property is set, the class should not be null, am i wrong in assuming so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 days and I finally figured out a solution.

```
<input type="hidden" name="department[id]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="department[name]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Name" />
```

Comment: I added the DataAttribute HiddenInput on my InputModel. That should work the same way. Why it isnt?

Answer (score 0):

Note : The model type of the submitted data in the form must be the same as the parameter type in the post method.

The value of `asp-for` in the input indicates that the `@model` in the View should be `CreateOrEditStoreWalkViewModel`, but from your screenshot , the type of parameter received in the method is `CreateOrEditStoreWalkDto`.

Try to changes you code of the action like the demo below

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void CreateStoreWalk(CreateOrEditStoreWalkViewModel createOrEditStoreWalkDto)
    {
        //the stuff you want
    }
```

Comment: That part of my code is actually correct. My `Post` is being sent to an `ApplicationService` using a dynamic web api rather than a controller, hence why most values are correctly set in the screenshot. The property in question is `Department` which is a class. I seem to only have an issue with classes, but I am confident this is not a limitation of any sort.